# Ubuntu detect memory leak

Tags: ubuntu, memory, process, memory-leaks

I run `watch free` and then observe a continuous memory used increment, about 100 every 2s. How can I know which process contribute to the used memory increment?

top and pmap does not help.

BTW, after I run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/VM/drop_caches`, the used memory decreased drastically. But it still keep increasing with the same rate.

Comment: '100 every 2s' ... 100 of what?

Comment: @akira: free reports kbytes by default, so probably "100s of kbytes".

Comment: To verify that it is a real leak and not caches/buffers: After "echo 1 > /proc/sys/VM/drop_caches", does it drop to the about the same lower value each time, or to a higher value each time? In the output from "free", does the value of "+/- buffers/cache" constantly increase, or only the value of "Mem"?

Answer (score 0):

I would use **top** and hit **shift-m** to sort on memory.  If an app is leaking memory it's **%MEM** should be increasing and the number under the **RES** column should be going up.

Above the list of the processes, if your **free** is going down, but **buffers** and **cache** are going up, while the apps in the list are about the same, then you should be fine.  This just means Linux is using your free RAM to avoid hitting your hard disk and such so it can run faster.  If you're worried about it still, open a bunch of applications and Linux should lower how much space it's using for the **cache** and **buffers** as the free gets close to 0.

When you tell it to **drop_caches**, Linux probably has to re-read the same area of the hard disk it just un-cached, and re-caches it.  We might be able to figure out how to limit the cache size if you really want to, but Linux is using your unused RAM to speed stuff up. Unless this is a laptop and you're trying to conserve power, you want it to use your RAM so it runs fast.